# Контент страницы зависимый от адреса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть страница с адресом: *http://.../index/11*

И страница с таким адресом: *http://.../index/11-2-5*

У этих страниц одно содержимое:

```
<div id="afg"></div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы на странице с адресом *http://.../index/11* в div была надпись: Страница 1, а на странице с адресом *http://.../index/11-2-5* содержимое у div было такое: Страница 2.

Это должен быть 1 скрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем делать все так трудно? Можно же просто сделать так:
`if(location.href=='*Атрес*'){и тут что оно должно выполнять}`

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте "**window.location.pathname**"

```
var message = window.location.pathname.indexOf('index/11-2-5') !== -1 ? 'Страница 1' : 'Страница 2';
$('#afg').html(message);
```

Comment: http://backbonejs.ru/#Router

Comment: @Павел Зайцев

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/application_architecture/router.html

https://github.com/polymerjs-tw/polymer-simple-router

продолжать ?

Comment: Для полноты коллекции ссылок ещё про HTML5 History API [пример](http://html5demos.com/history) приведу – смена URL (полноценного, без #хэша) без перезагузки страницы.